# Perl closing pipe without error

Tags: perl, pipe

I'm using Perl to execute an external programme and would like to end its execution if it returns a specific string while running. The code below interrupts the execution as desired, however an error message is returned when the last line (close) is executed.

```
open (my $out, "-|", "usfos $memory<input-$cpu.scr");
while (<$out>) {
    if ($_ =~ /MIN   STEP  LENGTH/) {
        last;
    }
}
close $out;
```

This is the part of the error that is printed (the external programme also returns error messages):

```
...forrtl: The pipe is being closed.
forrtl: severe (38): error during write, unit 6, file CONOUT$
```

So I think it's because Perl is trying to write to a closed handle. How can I avoid anything being printed?

Comment: perl isnt trying to write, this is a pipe to read not write. it seems like your external programe is the one giving the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `close $out` doesn't terminate the external program but closes its `STDOUT`.

In order to close the program you need to get its process id and then send it a suitable signal.  The `open` call returns the pid, just save it.  Then send a signal when the condition is met.

```
use Scalar::Util qw(openhandle); # to check whether the handle is open

my $pid = open (my $out, "-|", "usfos $memory<input-$cpu.scr") 
                // die "Can't fork: $!";   # / stop editor red coloring

while (<$out>) {
    if (/MIN   STEP  LENGTH/) {
        kill "TERM", $pid;   # or whatever is appropriate; add checks
        close $out;          # no check: no process any more so returns false
        last;
    }
}
# Close it -- if it is still open. 
if (openhandle($out)) {          
    close $out or warn "Error closing pipe: $!";
}
```

See
[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and
[opentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html), and
[close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html).

Fortran's error is indeed about writing to a non-existent console (`STDOUT`) so it seems that you diagnosed the problem correctly: as the condition is matched, you stop reading (`last`) and then close the program's `STDOUT`, which causes the reported error on its next attempted write.

A few notes. A `close` on the pipe waits for the other process to finish. If the program on the other end has a problem that is going to be known at `close`, so `$?` may need interrogation. If a pipe is closed before the other program is done writing on its next write to that pipe the program will get a `SIGPIPE`.  From [close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html)
documentation

> If the filehandle came from a piped open, close returns false if one of the other syscalls involved fails or if its program exits with non-zero status. If the only problem was that the program exited non-zero, $! will be set to 0 . Closing a pipe also waits for the process executing on the pipe to exit--in case you wish to look at the output of the pipe afterwards--and implicitly puts the exit status value of that command into $? and ${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE} .
> ...
> Closing the read end of a pipe before the process writing to it at the other end is done writing results in the writer receiving a SIGPIPE. If the other end can't handle that, be sure to read all the data before closing the pipe.

---

Note a little catch here. The objective is to kill a process while its `STDOUT` is connected to a filehandle *and* to close that filehandle (once a condition is met). If we first close the handle while the process may still write we may trigger a `SIGPIPE` to a process we may not know much about. (Does it handle the signal?) On the other hand, if we first terminate it the `close $out` cannot complete with success, since the process that `$out` was connected to is gone.

This is why the code does not check the return from the call to `close` after the process is killed, as it *is* false (if `kill` succeeded).  After the loop it checks whether the handle is still open before closing it, as we may or may have not closed it already.  Package [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.45/lib/Scalar/Util.pm) is used for this, another option being [fileno](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html). Note that the code doesn't check whether `kill` did the job, add that as needed.

---

On a Windows system, it is a little different since we need to find the process ID of the child. One can do this using its name and then terminate it either using [Win32::Process::Kill](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Process-Kill/lib/Win32/Process/Kill.pm), or `kill`. (Or, see a Windows command for this, below.)  To find the process ID try either of

- Using [Win32::Process::List](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erpagitsch/Win32-Process-List-0.09/List.pm)

  ```
    use Win32::Process::Kill;
    use Win32::Process::List;
    my $pobj = Win32::Process::List->new(); 
    my %proc = $pobj->GetProcesses(); 
    my $exitcode;
    foreach my $pid (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %proc) {
        my $name = $proc{$pid};
        if ($name =~ /usfos\.exe/) {
            Win32::Process::KillProcess($pid, \$exitcode);
            # kill 21, $pid;
            last;
        }
     }
  ```
- Using [Win32::Process::Info](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eplicease/Win32-Process-Info-1.022/lib/Win32/Process/Info.pm).  See [this post](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=509894).

  ```
  use Win32::Process::Info;
  Win32::Process::Info->Set(variant=>'WMI');   # SEE DOCS about WMI
  my $pobj = Win32::Process::Info->new();
  foreach my $pid ($pobj->ListPids) {
      my ($info) = $pobj->GetProcInfo($pid);
      if ($info->{CommandLine} =~ /^usfso/) {  # command-line, not name
          my $proc = $info->{ProcessId};
          kill 2, $proc; 
          last;
      }
  }
  ```

  This module also provides the method `Subprocesses([$ppid,...])`, which identifies all children of the submitted `$ppid`(s). It returns a hash, which is indexed by `$ppid`s and contains an array-ref with `$pid`s of all subprocesses, for each `$ppid` submitted.

  ```
  use Win32::Process::Info;
  Win32::Process::Info->Set(variant=>'WMI');
  my $pobj = Win32::Process::Info->new();
  my %subproc = $pobj->Subprocesses([$pid]);   # pid returned by open() call
  my $rkids = $subproc{$pid};
  foreach my $kid (@$rkids) {
      print "pid: $kid\n";                     # first check what is there
  }
  ```
- A Windows command `TASKKILL /T` should terminate a process and its children

  ```
  system("TASKKILL /F /T /PID $pid");
  ```

I cannot test any of Windows code right now.