# How can I gently kill a process in ActiveState Perl?

Tags: perl, kill-process, sigkill

Do I need to use an specific exitcode ?

```
Win32::Process::Create(
    $ProcessObj,
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",
    "firefox -no-remote -P $prof_name",
    0,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
".")|| die ErrorReport();
$ProcessObj->kill(0);
```

That way it kills, but not gently, it is generating problems with the Firefox profile.

Comment: If it's windowed app (as opposed to a console app), you can send a quit message to its message queue

Answer (score 6):

**Short**   Usual methods other than Window's `taskkill` are forceful. Thanks to [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) and [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene).

---

The [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejdb/Win32-Process-0.16/Process.pm) documentation doesn't say what the methods `Kill` or `KillProcess` do, but they seem pretty blunt about it. Windows does provide a gradation in how to terminate a process, see for example this post on [graceful termination via winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055753/how-to-gracefully-terminate-a-process), even as it does not have UNIX's signals. However, this is apparently not utilized by the module nor by `kill` (see end).

The Windows's own `taskkill` should nicely ask the process to terminate. Query it for flags, by running `taskkill /?` in a console on your system. Here is documentation for [taskkill on MS technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx). For example, this terminates the process by its `$pid`, along with its children

```
my $pid = $ProcessObj->GetProcessID();
system("taskkill /t /pid $pid");
```

If the method `GetProcessID()` doesn't return the real ID, see the link below for other ways.

I can't test on Windows right now. There's a bit more related detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470043/perl-closing-pipe-without-error/36470817#36470817), second part.

---

Perl's `kill` is apparently forceful on Windows. From [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#kill)

> ... `kill($sig, $pid)` terminates the process identified by `$pid`, and makes it exit immediately with exit status `$sig`.

Thanks to [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) for comment and documentation link.

The `exitcode`, I believe, only tells to process what to report to the system as its exit.

Comment: taskkill's `/F` flag means "and don't be gentle"

Comment: @mob Ah, thank you!  Corrected.  I should've known -- F may well stand for 'force'.

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals. On Windows, [`kill $n, $pid` forces the process `$pid` to exit with status `$n`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#kill).

Comment: @melpomene  _Forces_ it? Does it not send it the termination signal (Window's equivalent), or perhaps asks the OS to do so, allowing the process to clean up? If `$n` makes it exit with that status, then sending terminate should allow it to actually exit in that way? (Can't find any discussion of that in docs right now.)  I haven't touched winapi in a long while, but I think that there are various ways to terminate a process.  I'd expect `kill` to honor that?  Thank you for commenting.  **I see that it's a link only now, reading**

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know in Perl you could just do

```
kill -15 (pid)
```

Who gently kills a process in perl